# How to convert string to timestamp in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Please help me with my problem. I need to convert the string like Jan 1 2019 12:00AM to 2019-01-01 12:00:00 in snowflake. I am trying many ways but unfortunately I couldn't achieve it can you please help me.

```
SELECT to_timestamp('Jan 1 2019 12:00AM','MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS')      
FROM tablename;
```

error message :

> Can't parse 'Jan 1 2019 12:00AM' as timestamp with format 'MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS'

Comment: Timestamp formats are documented here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output#about-the-elements-used-in-input-and-output-formats

Answer (score 1):

here is the right date time formatting for given string:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('Jan 1 2019 12:00AM','MON DD YYYY HH12:MIAM')      
FROM tablename;
```

then you have to cast it to string with the format you want